How to re-export types the same way as modules?
First I had these files where one re-exports the other and it gets then re-exported from an index file.

model/index.ts
export * as api from './api'

model/api.ts
export * from "./api.routes"        // note #1

model/api.routes.ts
export type MyType = "hello"


I could then use the type from api namespace like this:
components/X.tsx
import { api } from '../model'

type T01 = api.MyType

However, I needed to remove the export #1 and move it directly in the model/index.ts file like so, ...
model/index.ts
import * as api_ from './api'
import * as routes from "./api.routes"

export api {
  ...api_,
  ...routes,
}

... but this now does not pass through the types. What can I do?
Cannot find namespace `api`

